# What's the size of the Merkle Tree of Masked Authenticated Messaging?

Tags: masked-authenticated-messaging

Based on [the current source code of the client](https://github.com/iotaledger/mam.client.js/blob/a365e8feb5d74c6e4a25b078433dffaead012428/src/index.js#L27) it looks like the Merkle Tree can have only one key.

Am I right?

The questions:

**How many keys does the Merkle Tree have in general?**

**What does it depend on?**

**How can the current message know how many keys the next Merkle Tree should have?**

Comment: The number of keys in the merkle tree is up to the user.

Comment: Hi. Are you Paul from Iota Foundation? If yes, can you explain me: what was the rationale behind using Merkle Trees here and not just single Winternits OST? How it can be useful to other users?

Comment: Hi @Paul such one-liners are more appropriate as comments. Feel free to add a formulated answer with some explanations if you can though.